# Mongodb limit number of records in collection

Tags: mongodb

I want to store my data in a collection that holds a maximum of ~10000 past records before they're deleted automatically from the database, like a FIFO queue of 10k records.

I have been looking at capped collections, but apart from the maximum number of records, they also require the maximum *size* of the collection. Now, I don't really know how much size 10k records are going to occupy. If I set a size that can't hold 10k records, I'll have lesser than I need. On the other hand, if I set an upper limit on the size, space is going to be wasted because mongo allocates the space beforehand.

What I can do is get dummy records, but I don't know how to check the size of each document.

Does anyone know of a method that can set an upper limit solely on the number of documents in my collection? Using the latest version on mongo out right now (v 3.6.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally push in 10000 actual real documents into a mongodb collection then call `stats` on the collection

```
db.test.stats()
```

Then use the size property:

```
> db.test.stats()
{
    "ns" : "test.test",
    "size" : 28609,
    "count" : 1018,
    "avgObjSize" : 28,
```

You may also want to add some padding, say 10% to that number:

```
cap col size = size * 1.1
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I could do that, but I wanted to know if it's possible without specifying the size. I was going to fall back to inserting dummy records and checking the size, but the number of fields in my documents will increase over time as development proceeds (More will be added as and when their collection code is ready). So I kinda wanted to get rid of that size component all together.

Comment: Looking at the docs it seems that it seems to be specified `size` but `max` is optional. So guess you will need to make up some size